# Adrotator image displaying

Tags: asp.net, adrotator

how can we include images in adrotator in asp.net?
`

```
<Advertisements>
  <Ad>
    <imageUrl>~/applee.jpg</imageUrl>
    <NavigateUrl>http://www.apple.com/in/</NavigateUrl>
     <AlternateText>APPLE MAC</AlternateText> 
  <Impressions>50</Impressions> 
  </Ad>`
```

Comment: you mean multiple images ?
cause I think your code is working after you check the address of the image

Answer (score 0):

```
<Advertisements>
  <Ad>
    <ImageUrl>images/applee.jpg</ImageUrl>
    <NavigateUrl>http://www.apple.com</NavigateUrl>
    <AlternateText>APPLE MAC</AlternateText> 
    <Impressions>50</Impressions> 
  </Ad>
</Advertisements>
```